# golang validation with gin-gonic

Tags: go, backend, go-gin

I'm trying to build a login API

```
type LoginRequest struct {
    Email    string `json:"email" binding:"required,email"`
    Password string `json:"password" binding:"required"`
}
func LoginHandler(app *config.Config) func(ctx *gin.Context) {
    return func(ctx *gin.Context) {
        var loginRequest LoginRequest
        if err := ctx.ShouldBindJSON(&loginRequest); err != nil {
            var ve validator.ValidationErrors
            if errors.As(err, &ve) {
                fmt.Println("validation error: ", ve)
                return
            }
            fmt.Printf("%T\n", err)
            fmt.Println("request content error: ", ve)
            return
        }
    }
}
```

and when I use curl as below:

```
curl --location --request POST '127.0.0.1:8080/api/login' \
--header 'Content-Type: application/json' \
--header 'Accept: application/json' \
--data-raw '{
    "password": "password"
}'
```

I get output in the terminal as follows:

```
validator.ValidationErrors
request content error:
```

despite the type of the variable `loginRequest` being `validator.ValidationErrors`, it couldn't be matched.

Comment: I'm not sure where validator.ValidationError is referenced from I think you should check like this ```errors.As(err, validator.ValidationErrors)```

Comment: Try explicitly asserting the type like `ve := err.(validator.ValidationErrors)` and see if that panics or not. If it panics - perhaps you have imported a different version (= different package) of `validator` than gin? Look at the last section of the import url.

Comment: I solved it just by replacing `"github.com/go-playground/validator"` with `"github.com/go-playground/validator/v10"`. Thanks @ErwinBolwidt